# SSRS MultiValue Parameter Default not Selecting Any

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am trying to make a **multi-value parameter** that's based off of a **dataset** to use **another** field for the **Default values**. I created a dataset for the parameter with the users and another column that substitutes an **X** for the **username** (op_user) if it's an automation account. Unfortunately, it's not selecting any of the usernames.

I have checked the data and there are **no NULL** values. I have ran a query to make sure that the columns are equal (the **Match** column).

[image: F.U. to all the cowardly down-voters who don't comment]

It works fine if I use the same **op_user** column for the default values but none are selected if I use the **OPuser** column.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone give me an idea of what else I can try in order to make this work?

Comment: What datatype is your parameter? `op_user` column contains numeric values `OPuser` doesn't

Comment: @alejandrozuleta - the columns are both nvar or var char and the parameter is text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I see is that your "Default Values" column of OPuser now contains an 'X' value that is not in your available values.  No values will be selected unless all the default values actually exist in the available values column.

I would suggest that you solve this problem with a second dataset.  Just use the logic to generate the OPuser column separately and then use that dataset as your default values.  That way you don't have to worry about the 'X' values that you don't actually want to be selected.

Comment: Ah - I had no idea of the requirement that all values exist. I ass**u**me d that it was like a JOIN and only matching values would appear. The query takes a couple of seconds. I think I'll try using a temp table and update the x to `max(op_user) where not x`. Hopefully multiple values don't freak it out.